# How to use scrollTo() function in Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html

What's wrong with my code? `scrollTo()` goes to the wrong position when I click and anchor with href value using hash # (div element ID).

This is my code, I just want to scroll to the comment element, but still overlap on the fixed header (bootstrap 5 fixed header).

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('a').length) {
        document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach( anchor => {
            anchor.addEventListener('click', event => {
                let URL = event.target.href.split('#');
                
                if (typeof URL[1] != undefined) {
                    let element = document.getElementById(URL[1]);
                    let offset = element.offsetTop;
                    let navigation = document.getElementById('main-navigation').clientHeight
                    let scroll = offset - navigation;
                    window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

[image: image1]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I suspect that some of the content from the comment is hidden behind the header? maybe try passing the height of the navigation manually and see if it works

Comment: How about a more complete [mcve]? Don't make us guess your markup. Also don't forget to cancel the default behaviour of clicking on an internal link, which may be what you are seeing here.

Comment: @JonP i just updated by question, using Bootstrap 5 with fixed header.

Comment: @Pranav still same problem

Comment: That's still not a [mcve], try to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Don't have us making assumptions, provide an example with enough code to **fully** replicate the problem.

Comment: call  `event.preventDefault()` in the click handler, otherwise after your call to `scrollTo`, the page's `hash` will change, with an automatic scroll to the anchored element overriding yours.

Comment: @Kaiido can you make answer instead of comment with the same text in above and then i will mark as correct answer? great!!! it's working properly thank you very much..

Comment: I was hoping to find a dupe, but I must admit that takes more time than expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `event.preventDefault()` in the *click* handler, otherwise after your call to `scrollTo`, the page's hash will change, with an automatic scroll to the anchored element overriding yours.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach( anchor => {
  anchor.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let URL = event.target.href.split('#');

    if (typeof URL[1] != undefined) {
      let element = document.getElementById(URL[1]);
      let offset = element.offsetTop;
      let navigation = document.querySelector('.over').clientHeight
      let scroll = offset - navigation;
      window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
      event.preventDefault(); // avoid internal scroll to anchor
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.over {
  height: 50px;
  background: salmon;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
#foo {
  margin-top: 250vh;
  height: 250vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo">#foo</a>
<div class="over"></div>

<div id="foo">Target element</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Kaiido.. you save my time.. but i hope Luffy wins the fight.

Comment: héhé it's actually entirely coincidental that my nickname (almost) matches the name of this character. I won't enter a fight.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using the `scrollIntoView()` function. see the below example. you have to target the element to scroll:

```js
let i = 0;
function myFunction() {
  if(i === 0){
    const elmnt = document.getElementById("content");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    i += 1
  }
  else {
    const elmnt = document.getElementById("content2");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView();
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: coral;
}
#content2 {
  margin:500px;
  height: 800px;
  width: 2000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to scroll to section.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Scroll</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  <div id="content">
  Some text inside an element.
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
  Some text inside an element.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the element is still covered by the fixed header.. check the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly you need to stop the default behavior. When an internal link is clicked the default action is to jump to that link. You need to override that.

Next, we can make a couple of little tweaks. First, only select internal links with an attribute selector that selects `a` tags where the href start with "#". Next, instead of splitting the url from the href, grab the raw value directly from the attribute.

```js
//Get internal links
document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='#']").forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    //Stops the inbuild scroll
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get the id straight from the attribute
    let selector = this.getAttribute("href");
    //Get the target element
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    //you know the rest
    let offset = element.offsetTop;
    let navigation = document.getElementById('main-navigation').clientHeight
    let scroll = offset - navigation;
    window.scrollTo(0, scroll);
  });
});
```

```css
/*CSS Purely for demo purposes.*/

.fixed-top {
  background-color: #EEE;
  padding: 15px;
}

article:first-of-type{
  margin-top:90px;
}

article {
  min-height: 50vh;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

nav {
  background-color: #ECECEC;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="fixed-top" id="main-navigation">Some Top Stuff
  <nav>
    <a href="#art1">Article 1</a>
    <a href="#art2">Article 2</a>
    <a href="#art3">Article 3</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<article id="art1">
  <h1>Article 1</h1>
</article>
<article id="art2">
  <h1>Article 2</h1>
</article>
<article id="art3">
  <h1>Article 3</h1>
</article>
```

Comment: What a funny edit that came in here.